# Kivy Random Screenmanager auto change screen with some delay

Tags: python, kivy

I need to have Kivy screen manager with random number of screen , each screen have some Image. Im trying to display each screen one by one with some delay.
I am able to achieve it partially. when I run my App it shows 1st screen only, with a next button i move to next screen(Image) and then after it continue to show screen until it reaches to last one.

code looks like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
import time

Builder.load_string('''
#:import random random.random

#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition

<CustomScreen>:
    Image:
        source: root.name

    Button:
        text: 'Next screen'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'right': 1}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.callbackfun()
''')


class CustomScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self,*args):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print "on Enter"
        if self.manager.current != "image10.jpg":
            self.callbackfun()
    def callbackfun(self):
        print "Change Screen"
        print self.manager.current
        print self.manager.next()
        self.manager.current = self.manager.next()

class ScreenManagerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        root = ScreenManager(transition = NoTransition(duration = 0))
        for x in range(11):
            print "add", x
            root.add_widget(CustomScreen(name='image%d.jpg' % x))
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

At first *`print self.manager.current`* and *`print self.manager.next()`* both shows `0` but after button press, it shows current and next screen correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

Using *time.sleep* in Kivy application.

[Programming Guide » Events and Properties » Main Loop](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html)

> In Kivy applications, you have to avoid *long/infinite loops* or
>   *sleeping* e.g. *time.sleep()* This is preventing Kivy from doing all of the other things that need doing.

## Solution

You can call a function or a method every X times per second using *Clock.schedule_interval()*, or using *Clock.schedule_once()*, you can call a function “later”, like in the next frame, or in X seconds.

Replaced *time.sleep(0.5)* with *Clock.schedule_once()*. Please refer to the example below for details.

### Snippets

```
class CustomScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        if self.manager.current != "image5.png":
            Clock.schedule_once(self.callbackfun, 0.5)
```

### Example

#### mainButton.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_string('''
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock

<CustomScreen>:
    Image:
        source: root.name

    Button:
        text: 'Next screen'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'right': 1}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: 
            Clock.schedule_once(root.callbackfun, 0.5)
''')


class CustomScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        print("on Enter")
        if self.manager.current != "image5.png":
            Clock.schedule_once(self.callbackfun, 0.5)

    def callbackfun(self, dt):
        print("Change Screen")
        print(self.manager.current)
        print(self.manager.next())
        self.manager.current = self.manager.next()


class ScreenManagerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        root = ScreenManager(transition = NoTransition(duration = 0))
        for x in range(6):
            print("add", x)
            root.add_widget(CustomScreen(name='image%d.png' % x))
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much once again! :-)

Comment: i think you should use carousel for such cases

Comment: @Joeydanieldarko Thanks for advice, But As i know carousel is for Image slide show. In my application, I dont want Images to slide. That's why i choose 'NoTransition'  in 'screenmanager'. Also the delay between two consecutive images may change in my application. I'm working on it